# Automapper after mapping to existing object ef core can't track changes

Tags: c#, automapper, ef-core-2.0

After pulling the list of objects(entities) from the database, I want to update those objects but only certain properties and save changes to DB, after mapping is done it lose track of changes and context is not showing any changes.

I tried making custom value resolver for AutoMapper and I failed miserably since ips are still 0 after mapping.

#### So here is the code snippet

```
class A { int id; string Name; }
class B { string Name;} 
List<B> b = new List<B>() { "t", "g" };

var result = ctx.A.ToList();
this.Mapper.Map<IList<B>,IList<A>>(b,result);
ctx.A.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't change `result`, so there is nothing to change.  And in your mappings you have `(A,B)` which won't compile because they aren't variables, they are classes.

Comment: U are right i missed that

Comment: Check AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a List of items.

```
this.Mapper.Map<IList<B>,IList<A>>(b,result);
```

Says, map `B` values to `result` values... but don't change `result` to a new object type, which it isn't.  Nothing in this code tells AutoMapper not to change the items *in the list*.

This is because there is no way for Automapper to correlation which items in `b` should map to which items in `result`.  Additionally, what should it do if the number of items are different?

You can force it yourself using:

```
result = result
  .Zip(b, (r,b2) => mapper.Map<B,A>(b2,r) )
  .ToList()
```

[DotNetFiddleExample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOaOkt)

Comment: I know that list will be the same size, and tnx you were right I thought about the coloration of 2 lists but yea I didn't know about Zip function.